# Postgresql statement in psycopg2 not returning expected values

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have a postgresql database established. I run the following code to get unique values in the 'state' column of the table (these are strings that represent FIPS numbers):

```
import psycopg2 as ps
con = ps.connect("dbname=example_db user=user password=password")
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT(%s) FROM example_table', ('state',))
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

This returns:

```
results
('state',)
```

If I run the same query in PGAdmin4 I get:

```
example_db=# SELECT DISTINCT state FROM example_table;

state
-------
06
(1 row)
```

I want to get the distinct values (i.e., 06, in this case) using psycopg2. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
from psycopg2 import sql
cursor.execute(sql.SQL('SELECT DISTINCT {} FROM example_table').format(sql.Identifier('state')))
```

The issue is `state` is an identifier(column name) and you can't use parameters to include that in the query. You need to use the [psycopg2.sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql) module to build the identifier into the query.

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea that I couldn't use parameters for identifiers. But, I played around with it and I can if I alias the table name, i.e., this works:             cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT a.state FROM example_table a'); Not sure why this would be allowed?

Comment: What you show does not use parameters so yes it would work , as well as `cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT state FROM example_table')`.

Comment: Oh. Duh. You're right. I thought I tried that (i.e., cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT state FROM example_table') and it didn't work, but just tried again and it did. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Names of database objects, such as table or column names, cannot pass as SQL string literals for escaping.
See the **psycopg2.sql** [module](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html)

```
import psycopg2 as ps
con = ps.connect("dbname=example_db user=user password=password")
cursor = con.cursor()
query = ps.sql.SQL('SELECT DISTINCT {column_name} FROM example_table').format(column_name=sql.Identifier('state'))
cursor.execute(query)
```